# Laravel Auth Login by company name, username, and password

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I like user to login by company name, username, and password - they need to enter all those fields.

`username`, and `password` fields are in the `users` table.
`company_name` are in the `companies` table.

`username` can be duplicated in the `users` table but each username is belong to different company name. `company_id` is defined in `users` table.

How can I Auth against company name, username, and password?

I had a look at the `attemptLogin()` method.

```
 protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->guard()->attempt(
            $this->credentials($request), $request->has('remember')
        );
    }
```

I can't override this because I need to pass specific user that is belong to company then do auth check.

Update:

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, User $user)
{
    if (!$user->enable) {
        Auth::logout();

        return redirect('/login')->with('status', 'Account is disabled');
    }

    return redirect()->intended('/');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `username` and `company_name` pair is unique, you can do this:

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::where('username', $request->username)
        ->where(function ($q) use ($request) {
            q->whereHas('company', function ($q) use ($request) {
                $q->where('company_name', $request->company_name);
            })
            ->orWhereHas('warehouse', function ($q) use ($request) {
                $q->where('company_name', $request->company_name);
            });
        })
        ->first();

    return !is_null($user) && \Hash::check($request->password, $user->password));
}

protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'company_name' => 'required',
        'username' => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that in the user table it can be company_id or warehouse_id. If company_id is null then check warehouse_id against `warehouses` table which also have `company_name`

Comment: In case you want it nice and clean make your own guard and focus on `attempt()` method.

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back I've updated the answer, it'll work for you if you defined `warehouse` and `company` relations correctly.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Thank you, I will test it now. @Kyslik mention to make own guard? so I can create another in `auth.php` in config file?

Comment: Read docs about making your own guard (I am on the phone cant link you); after that you change config file so your shiny guard is the default one. By doing all this you will move responsibility for attempting to login to the guard, and your controller might be thinner by few lines.

Comment: @Kyslik I am trying to create own guard  - there is no `attempt()` method in  Guard interface. Eg:  `class BackendSessionGuard implements Guard { }`

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Your code is working fine and auth passed - then I get an error: `Type error: Argument 2 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::authenticated() must be an instance of App\User, null given`

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back sounds like you did override this method too. Please show the method.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I have just added `authenticated` method to my question.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I have managed to fix it by doing this:         `if (!is_null($user)) {
            return $this->guard()->attempt([
                'username' => $user->username,
                'password' => $request->password,
            ]);
        }` if this is the right way.

Answer (score -2):

You can DIY the login Request or Controller , such like that

```
// find user
$user = User::where...

// check user
// ...

// make he login
auth()->login($user);
```

---

Also, if you have the company_id field in users table.

It's belongs to  One To One eloquent-relationships.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

---

So you can use this method.

```
   $user_company_name =  User::first()->company_name;
```

you could be check this thing .

Comment: Because your answer is far from the sollution, and its unusable.